# Candidate note data unable to be posted to PHP section of page?

Tags: php, forms, post

My php page has the HTML and PHP all on the same page.

For the HTML section, user data is inputted and posted to the PHP section.

```
</div>
</header>
<pre>



</pre>
    <h1 style="font-family: 'Lucida Sans Typewriter'"> Note entry:</h1>

<form method="post">
<div>
        <div style="margin-right:5px;">
            <input type="text" class="fileName" name="fileName" id="fileName" size="35" 
value="untitled">
            <input type="text" name="noteData" id="notes" size="250">
            <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Save">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As for the PHP section, I check to see if a POST has occured, then save file and filename to disk, yet this does not occur.

```
        if($_POST){
            $noteName = $_POST['fileName'];
            $noteData = $_POST['notes'];
            $notes = fopen('' + $noteName,"wb");
            fwrite($notes,$noteData);
            fclose($notes);
        }
```

The errors thrown are here:

https://gyazo.com/99646e2705ed7ea927d27c67cddb87b4

Any suggestions? I need this finished soon and cannot for the life of me discover why this is deciding not to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use names to get data using $_POST. And use `.` to concatenate words in php. So change the line as:

```
if($_POST){
   $noteName = $_POST['fileName'];
   $noteData = $_POST['noteData'];
   $notes = fopen('' . $noteName,"wb");
   fwrite($notes,$noteData);
   fclose($notes);
}
```

Comment: works perfectly now, I added a .  '.txt' concatenation to make it a txt file, but my issue now is that the input area size needs to be much larger but I can't find how to increase the height of the input area

Answer (score 0):

You should use names, not ID. Try $_POST[‘noteData’].